# How to pass main query column to nested sub query?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am writing a query, which has nested queryies in select statement as below.

```
Select t1.R1,
  (
    select * from
    (
      select t2.R2
      from table2 t2
      where t2.Condition_1=t1.C1
      order by t2.Condition_2 desc
    )
    where rownum=1
  ),
  t1.R3
from table1 t1
```

I am trying to pass main queries object into a sub query inside a sub query in select statement.

When I execute this I am getting  object invalid error at `t1.C1`.

I am able to pass object of the main table `table1` to the first sub query, but how can I pass the `table1` column to sub query inside a sub query?

Can any please help me in this scenario?

Comment: You can only refer to objects down to one level of subquery, so `t1` just isn't recognised in the inner subquery. Why are you using a subquery instead of a join?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. i am using sub queries because the table2, which I am calling, have duplicate rows for each ID I need to take latest updated dates row. I tried using joins but it is giving duplicate rows around 300 rows extra. is there any alternative for this instead of sub query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only refer to objects down to one level of subquery, so `t1` just isn't recognised in the inner subquery.

There are a few ways to do this. Sticking with your current subquery, you can make that into an in-line view and join to that instead:

```
select t1.r1, t2.r2, t1.r3
from table1 t1
join (
  select *
  from (
    select condition_1, r2
    from table2
    order by condition_2 desc
  )
  where rownum = 1
) t2 on t2.condition_1 = t1.c1;
```

The subquery finds one `table2` record for each `condition_1`, based on your ordering criteria; then that single row can be joined to a single row from `table1` (assuming `c1` is unique).

Or you could use an analytic function:

```
select r1, r2, r3
from (
  select t1.r1, t2.r2, t1.r3,
    row_number() over (partition by t2.condition_1 
      order by t2.condition_2 desc) as rn
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.condition_1 = t1.c1
)
where rn = 1;
```

This joins the two tables and then decides which of the `table2` values to retain by looking at the already-joined result set, based on the ordering condition in the analytic function's windowing clause. The inner query run on its own would produce what you saw when you tried to join before, with all the 'duplicates' (not really duplicates in the result set, but multiple rows for each `r1`/`r3` pair from `table1`), with an addition `rn` column that ranks those result set rows within those duplicates; the outer query then filters that to only shows the rows ranked first.

[SQL Fiddle demo of both approaches](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c60283/2).

If `condition_2` isn't unique then you'd need to decide how to handle ties - if `table2` could have two `r2` values for the same `condition_1` and `condition_2` combination. You could look at a different analytic function in that case - `rank` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know its bit old but it may help others. You can take the where clause out from the sub sub query and keep that clause where it is accessible.

```
Select t1.R1,
  (
    select * from
      (
        select t2.R2
        from table2 t2
      ) x
      where x.Condition_1=t1.C1
      order by x.Condition_2 desc
    )
    where rownum=1
  ),
  t1.R3
from table1 t1
```